# Angular2 and rxjs 'Catch' Operator not working

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

[Plnkr Link With Working Code](https://embed.plnkr.co/yvgkJzXrMULIeiZO4q2W/)

I am trying to copy the working code from Plnkr to my machine and it's showing error in the VisualStudio.

Currently I am using `@angular "^2.4.5"` and `rxjs "^5.2.0"`

[image]

The error is saying that

> Argument of type '(error: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable) => ObservableInput<{}>'.

You can see in my following script that I copied exactly similar to the Plnkr code and imported 'catch' operator.  However, it's not working and showing the above error in `getStudentCourse2()` method.

If I removed catch operator and changed the code like the one in `getStudentCourse()` method, it works and I can see the result.

**student.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

@Injectable()
export class StudentService {
    private http: Http;            

    constructor(http: Http) {
        this.http = http;        
    }

    getStudentCourse(): Observable<IStudentCourse> {

        return this.http.get('/api/student/getstudentcourse').map(result => {
            return result.json() as IStudentCourse;
        }, error => console.log('Could not load data in service.'));

    }

    getStudentCourse2(): Observable<IStudentCourse> {

        return this.http.get('https://58cff77fe1a0d412002e446d.mockapi.io/api/student/getstudentcourse/2').map(result => {
            return result.json() as IStudentCourse;
        }).catch(error => console.log('Could not load data in service.'));

    }
}

export interface IStudentCourse {
    refNo: string;
    student: string;
    offeringName: string;
    offeringID: number;
}
```

I couldn't find out why 'Catch' operator is not working in my code like 'Plnkr'.  Could you guys please help me with this issue?  Thanks.

Comment: you can an Observable object in catch operator.For example see the below code :         return this.http.get('https://58cff77fe1a0d412002e446d.mockapi.io/api/student/getstudentcourse/2').map(result => {
            return result.json() as IStudentCourse;
        }).catch(error => Observable.throw('Could not load data in service.'));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from the fact that the catch method must return an Observable, but your code doesn't really return an Observable.

You can easily fix the issue with the following code:

```
return this.http.get('https://58cff77fe1a0d412002e446d.mockapi.io/api/student/getstudentcourse/2').map(result => {
            return result.json() as IStudentCourse;
        }).catch(error => Observable.throw(error));
```

However, I would suggest an another pattern for this problem that would actually make your code a bit cleaner in my opinion.

Instead of using .catch method you can just easily create an ExceptionService(for example) with a HandlException method and just pass the error to that method and handle the error there.

Your code would look something like this:

```
return this.http.get('https://58cff77fe1a0d412002e446d.mockapi.io/api/student/getstudentcourse/2').map(result => {
                return result.json() as IStudentCourse;
            },
            error => this._exceptionService.HandleError(error));
)
```

(Having said that you injected the _exceptionService in your component)

By doing the handling this way, your code becomes cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

The `catch` operator needs to return an `Observable` but you are returning `void` due to `console.log` is always returning `void`. Return an `Observable` and the error will go away.

For example:

```
...
.catch(error => {
  console.log('something went wrong');
  return Observable.throw(new Error('throw a fancy new error'));
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is saying this; callback in `catch` operator does not return anything. You can throw error in `catch` operator and handle this error when you subscribe;

```
getStudentCourse(){
     return this.http.get(parameters).map(handleData).catch(error => {
          Observable.throw(error);
     });
}

getStudentCourse().subscribe(successCallback, (error) => {
     // do whatever you want with this error
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The `catch` needs to return an `Observable` or `throw` something. When you return an observable it will enter the success method in your subscribe. When you throw something it will enter your error method. Check the answer I gave to your previous question. [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/m8YvbuzEfQqH2NKht8jU?p=preview)